# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) - Nougat only

Tags: android, crash, segmentation-fault, native, google-play-console

I get **signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)** native crashes. *40 user impacted (153 total reports) with 400k active installs on 60 days period.*

More info:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000001e84914  /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk
  #01  pc 0000000001e84900  /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk
```

What is interesting the problem occurs only on Android 7.0 and 7.1

Comment: I'm getting similar error, any update regarding this issue? did you find the solution?